# How to programmatically set style attribute in a view

Tags: android, styles

I'm getting a view from the XML with the code below:

```
Button view = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.section_button, null);
```

I would like to set a "style" for the button how can I do that in java since a want to use several style for each button I will use.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

Generally you can't change styles programmatically; you can set the look of a screen, or part of a layout, or individual button in your XML layout using [themes or styles](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html).  Themes can, however, [be applied programmatically](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html#fromTheApp).

There is also such a thing as a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html) which lets you define different drawables for each state the your `Button` can be in, whether focused, selected, pressed, disabled and so on.

For example, to get your button to change colour when it's pressed, you could define an XML file called `res/drawable/my_button.xml` directory like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item
    android:state_pressed="true"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_pressed" />
  <item
    android:state_pressed="false"
    android:drawable="@drawable/btn_normal" />
</selector>
```

You can then apply this selector to a `Button` by setting the property `android:background="@drawable/my_button"`.

Comment: My problem is that I load data from a webservice that describe my button info. The buttons need to have different style based on a category they belong. That's why I would like to set style dynamicly.

Comment: Well you can't change the Android `style` attribute, but you can programmatically set the background of an `Button` like you can with any other view, if that will suffice. Also, as a `Button` inherits from `TextView`, you can change text properties. Just look at the API documentation for these items... http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setBackgroundResource%28int%29

Comment: I was just thinking about doing that, right before checking if I had new answers. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is it not possible to create a style for a button which defines the text size, margins etc etc and then apply this to a button programatically. Surely its possible say if I have six buttons which want to have the same style?

Comment: which attribute we can inflate ?  can we inflate margins , padding ?

Answer (score 65):

First of all, you don't need to use a layout inflater to create a simple Button. You can just use:

```
button = new Button(context);
```

If you want to style the button you have 2 choices: the simplest one is to just specify all the elements in code, like many of the other answers suggest:

```
button.setTextColor(Color.RED);
button.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, 18);
```

The other option is to define the style in XML, and apply it to the button. In the general case, you can use a [`ContextThemeWrapper`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/ContextThemeWrapper.html) for this:

```
ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.MyStyle);
button = new Button(newContext);
```

To change the text-related attributes on a TextView (or its subclasses like Button) there is a special method:

```
button.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyTextStyle);
```

Or, if you need to support devices pre API-23 (Android 6.0)

```
button.setTextAppearance(context, R.style.MyTextStyle);
```

This method cannot be used to change all attributes; for example to change padding you need to use a `ContextThemeWrapper`. But for text color, size, etc. you can use [`setTextAppearance`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Comment: Just brilliant. ContextThemeWrapper - is what I was looking for so long time.

Comment: This works fantastically. Been looking for this solution for awhile.

Comment: That version of setTextAppearance has been deprecated.  You can just use button.setTextAppearance(R.style.MyTextStyle);

Comment: `ContextThemeWrapper newContext = new ContextThemeWrapper(baseContext, R.style.MyStyle);
button = new Button(newContext);` suppose to choose the style on button creation. What if I need to change the style after creating the button?

Answer (score 16):

You can do style attributes like so:

```
Button myButton = new Button(this, null,android.R.attr.buttonBarButtonStyle);
```

in place of:

```
<Button
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    style="?android:attr/buttonBarButtonStyle"

    />
```

Comment: Good answer considering a button shall be created. Would be nice to see how to do that for an existing button.

Comment: See the answer from cesards.

Answer (score 15):

Yes, you can use for example in a button

```
Button b = new Button(this);
b.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.selector_test);
```

Comment: That will set the background but a style can specify more than just a background.  A lot of Views (including Button) seem to have a constructor that takes a style ID as a parameter.  However, I'm having problems getting that to work for me - the button shows up as text with no border or anything.  What I might do instead is create a layout with only a button in it (with a style specified), inflate that layout, then set the button text and whatnot.

Answer (score 12):

If you are using the Support library, you could simply use

```
TextViewCompat.setTextAppearance(textView, R.style.AppTheme_TextStyle_ButtonDefault_Whatever);
```

for TextViews and Buttons. There are similar classes for the rest of Views :-)

Comment: which R package do you need to use to get this style?

Answer (score 7):

Depending on what style attributes you'd like to change you may be able to use the Paris library:

```
Button view = (Button) LayoutInflater.from(this).inflate(R.layout.section_button, null);
Paris.style(view).apply(R.style.YourStyle);
```

Many attributes like background, padding, textSize, textColor, etc. are supported.

- [List of currently supported attributes](https://github.com/airbnb/paris/wiki/Supported-View-Types-and-Attributes)
- [Installation instructions](https://github.com/airbnb/paris/blob/master/README.md#installation)

Disclaimer: I authored the library.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by @Dayerman and @h_rules is right. 
To give an elaborated example with code,
In drawable folder, create an xml file called button_disabled.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" android:padding="10dp">   
 <solid android:color="@color/silver"/>
<corners
   android:bottomRightRadius="20dp"
   android:bottomLeftRadius="20dp"
   android:topLeftRadius="20dp"
   android:topRightRadius="20dp"/>
</shape>
```

Then in Java,

```
((Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setEnabled(false);
((Button) findViewById(R.id.my_button)).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.button_disabled);
```

This will set the button's property to disabled and sets the color to silver.

[The color is defined in color.xml as:

```
<resources>

    <color name="silver">#C0C0C0</color>

</resources>
```

Comment: @Pacerier: the question doesn't say that at all. It's ambiguous whether the style is XML or in java. It only asks how to set the style programmatically.

Answer (score 6):

For anyone looking for a Material answer see this SO post: [Coloring Buttons in Android with Material Design and AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat)

I used a combination of this answer to set the default text color of the button to white for my button: 
https://stackoverflow.com/a/32238489/3075340

Then this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/34355919/3075340 to programmatically set the background color. The code for that is:

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(your_colored_button,
 ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),R.color.your_custom_color));
```

`your_colored_button` can be just a regular `Button` or a AppCompat button if you wish - I tested the above code with both types of buttons and it works.

EDIT: I found that pre-lollipop devices do not work with the above code. See this post on how to add support for pre-lollipop devices: https://stackoverflow.com/a/30277424/3075340

Basically do this:

```
Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
ColorStateList c = ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.your_custom_color;
Drawable d = b.getBackground();
if (b instanceof AppCompatButton) {
    // appcompat button replaces tint of its drawable background
    ((AppCompatButton)b).setSupportBackgroundTintList(c);
} else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
    // Lollipop button replaces tint of its drawable background
    // however it is not equal to d.setTintList(c)
    b.setBackgroundTintList(c);
} else {
    // this should only happen if 
    // * manually creating a Button instead of AppCompatButton
    // * LayoutInflater did not translate a Button to AppCompatButton
    d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(d, c);
    b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

At runtime, you know what style you want your button to have. So beforehand, in xml in the layout folder, you can have all ready to go buttons with the styles you need. So in the layout folder, you might have a file named: button_style_1.xml. The contents of that file might look like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Button
    android:id="@+id/styleOneButton"
    style="@style/FirstStyle" />
```

If you are working with fragments, then in onCreateView you inflate that button, like:

```
Button firstStyleBtn = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_style_1, container, false);
```

where container is the ViewGroup container associated with the onCreateView method you override when creating your fragment.

Need two more such buttons? You create them like this:

```
Button secondFirstStyleBtn = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_style_1, container, false);
Button thirdFirstStyleBtn = (Button) inflater.inflate(R.layout.button_style_1, container, false);
```

You can customize those buttons:

```
secondFirstStyleBtn.setText("My Second");
thirdFirstStyleBtn.setText("My Third");
```

Then you add your customized, stylized buttons to the layout container you also inflated in the onCreateView method:

```
_stylizedButtonsContainer = (LinearLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.stylizedButtonsContainer);

_stylizedButtonsContainer.addView(firstStyleBtn);
_stylizedButtonsContainer.addView(secondFirstStyleBtn);
_stylizedButtonsContainer.addView(thirdFirstStyleBtn);
```

And that's how you can dynamically work with stylized buttons.

Answer (score 0):

I made a helper interface for this using the holder pattern.

```
public interface StyleHolder<V extends View> {
    void applyStyle(V view);
}
```

Now for every style you want to use pragmatically just implement the interface, for example:

```
public class ButtonStyleHolder implements StyleHolder<Button> {

    private final Drawable background;
    private final ColorStateList textColor;
    private final int textSize;

    public ButtonStyleHolder(Context context) {
        TypedArray ta = context.obtainStyledAttributes(R.style.button, R.styleable.ButtonStyleHolder);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();

        background = ta.getDrawable(ta.getIndex(R.styleable.ButtonStyleHolder_android_background));

        textColor = ta.getColorStateList(ta.getIndex(R.styleable.ButtonStyleHolder_android_textColor));

        textSize = ta.getDimensionPixelSize(
                ta.getIndex(R.styleable.ButtonStyleHolder_android_textSize),
                resources.getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.standard_text_size)
        );

        // Don't forget to recycle!
        ta.recycle();
    }

    @Override
    public void applyStyle(Button btn) {
        btn.setBackground(background);
        btn.setTextColor(textColor);
        btn.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX, textSize);
    }
}
```

Declare a stylable in your `attrs.xml`, the styleable for this example is:

```
<declare-styleable name="ButtonStyleHolder">
    <attr name="android:background" />
    <attr name="android:textSize" />
    <attr name="android:textColor" />
</declare-styleable>
```

Here is the style declared in `styles.xml`:

```
<style name="button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/button</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/light_text_color</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/standard_text_size</item>
</style>
```

And finally the implementation of the style holder:

```
Button btn = new Button(context);    
StyleHolder<Button> styleHolder = new ButtonStyleHolder(context);
styleHolder.applyStyle(btn);
```

I found this very helpful as it can be easily reused and keeps the code clean and verbose, i would recommend using this only as a local variable so we can allow the garbage collector to do its job once we're done with setting all the styles.

Answer (score 0):

```
fun Context.wrapWithStyles(@StyleRes styleRes: Int): Context {
    val theme = resources.newTheme()
    theme.setTo(this.theme)
    theme.applyStyle(styleRes, true)
    return ContextThemeWrapper(this, theme)
}
```

Usage:

```
TextClock(context.wrapWithStyles(R.style.TextClockStyle))
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

I faced the same problem recently. here is how i solved it.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!-- This is the special two colors background START , after this LinearLayout, you can add all view that have it for main background-->
    <LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"

    android:weightSum="2"

    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#0000FF" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:background="#F000F0" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <!-- This is the special two colors background END-->

   <TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerInParent="true"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="This Text is centered with a special backgound,
    You can add as much elements as you want as child of this RelativeLayout"
    android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
    android:textSize="20sp" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

- I used a LinearLayout with android:weightSum="2"
- I gave to the two child elements android:layout_weight="1"
  (I gave each 50% of the parent space(width & height))
- And finally, i gave the two child element different background colors to have the final effect.

Thanks !