# Is it possible to have a Button with a background image with text on top?

Tags: android, button, imageview

I need button that has a replicated background pattern and normal button text on top - how to specify this in layout XML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override `android:background` on the `Button` in question.  Or, for reuse you could declare your own style, overriding `android:background` from the base button style:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="MyButtonStyle" parent="Widget.Button">
    <item name="android:background">@drawable/fancy_button</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

In either case, your `fancy_button` drawable would be an image, or more likely a [`StateListDrawable`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/StateListDrawable.html).

For the `Button` instances you wish to apply this to, you'd do:
`<Button style="@style/MyButtonStyle" />`.

Comment: @Chris: I hadn't looked at the styling/theming in Android and that is a good approach to me.

Comment: @Chris: Im assuming StateListDrawable allows me to swap images based on state? How would I use that for my buttons?

Comment: See the example here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view/2016344#2016344
You just declare which image you want to show when the button is focused/pressed/disabled/none-of-the-above etc.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [ImageButton](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageButton.html) instead of using regular one.

Comment: `ImageButton` doesn't allow you to set a text label.

Comment: Will ImageButton replicate the background image?