# How to set ratingbar style from programmatically?

Tags: android, rating

I don't see any method like setStyle for class RatingBar. How can I set the rating style from code?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view

Comment: NOT a duplicate.  A ratingbar has different properties and functionality. Things like setting the star images, star height, etc WILL NOT be answered by that question.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This works for me ([source](http://www.mentby.com/abangkis/)):

```
RatingBar rating =
  new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);
```

Comment: This is not working any event but view is working file

Answer (score 2):

You need to set it in xml file! If you like to change it on the run, you can have two different View-s (rb) and switch them in the program (add/remove from layout) or use rb1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE) and rb2.setVisibility(View.GONE);

```
<RatingBar 
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true" android:id="@+id/rb1"
    style="?android:attr/ratingBarStyleSmall"
    android:clickable="false" android:numStars="5">
</RatingBar>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are programmatically creating the RatingBar as follows the

`RatingBar rating = new RatingBar(context, null, android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall);`

then don't for get to add

`rating.setIsIndicator(false);`

else the touch will not work on RatingBar.

The `android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleSmall` gives you very small stars if you want to have a slightly bigger stars use `android.R.attr.ratingBarStyleIndicator`