# adding the style attribute via code

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to programmatically setting style attribute in a view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view)

hello

I was wondering how to assign a style via code in adroid.

suppose I have a TextView created with the following snippet:

```
TextView myText = new TextView(this);
```

how do I assign the class xxx so that myText will be styled like an hard coded TextView like this:

```
<TextView style="@style/xxx" />
```

thanks