# Button setBackgroundColor no highlight effect

Tags: android, button, colors, background, highlight

When I create a Button,

```
Button myButton = new Button(this);
myButton.setText("Click Me!");
```

it creates a button, that on click, turns "Orange" to indicate the click.

To the button when I add,

```
button.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
```

It creates a blue rectangle, and on click does not have a hightlight effect.

I don't mind the rectangle part, I want to get the orange highlight effect though.

Cannot use XML, need to do this in code.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For setting background color/image and having click highlight effect....you have set the style/theme for the button.

The style/theme contains the color attributes for various states of button such as focused / enabled / disabled/ etc.

Comment: @chris....Generally you cant change style of any control programmatically...refer this answer(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view/2016344#2016344) this makes your doubt clear.....

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem with you and fixed it strangely. You need to type `button.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);`, because we didn't import class `android.graphics.Color`. Good luck! :D.