# Show selected button

Tags: android, android-layout

I have a group of buttons which enable user to select certain views on the touch screen.

I want to have the user know which view is active by showing a halo (or any other style) around the button. I mean when the button is clicked it's normal state is changed to different style but it is still normal.

I googled and checked in stackoverflow, that it is not possible to change the style at runtime.
How can I achieve the desired effect?
I have some silly ideas which I won't implement unless as last resort, like making two buttons at same positions and changing their visibility.
Or I can put each button in it's own linear layout and then set the background color of each of them, if it is possible.
Or some ImageButton manipulation maybe.

I have already overridden the default style for button for normal pressed states.
And setting focus(when in focusInTouchMode) causes problem, so that's a NO (already tried that).

Even if style can't be changed, please advise some tip to achieve the effect, it's not necessary to do it the style way. I just want o let the user know which view is selected through buttons.

[image: example image]

Answer (score 1):

use state list and set its focussed state drawable as the button with a ring around it and then at runtime say `button.requestFocus()`. see [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/drawable-resource.html) for more on state list...

Comment: Setting focus was my first Idea, but I don't know why setting focus messes around with my code.

Comment: Then thats the real problem and not what you have currently posted.. why don't you post your code and show us what have you tried..

Comment: Actually setting focus, doesn't causes problem with these buttons, but some other button. When I set and use focus, if I use H/W buttons they work fine, but when I touch them, some other corresponding button work diffrently. They don't crash or anything. That's why I don't think it should be done with focus states.

Answer (score 0):

Go for selector xml background for each button. Best Resort

Check this link
[How to set image button backgroundimage for different state?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4755871/how-to-set-image-button-backgroundimage-for-different-state)

Hpoe this helps

Comment: I have already set different states, I want 2 normal states, when showing corresponding view is selected or not.

Answer (score 0):

or you can use like ::

```
Button button;
public void onClick(View v)
{
    button.button.setBackgroundColor(**color**);
    button.setBackgroundResource(**res**)
}
```

Comment: You may want to refer to [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3297027/button-setbackgroundcolor-no-highlight-effect)