# Using a variable in android XML or otherwise programmatically setting an XML attribute

Tags: android, xml, android-xml

Say I have a style that I want to change:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
<style parent="Widget.TitlePageIndicator" name="Widget.MyTitlepageIndicator">
    <item name="footerColor">#14A804</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

And I want to change the value of "footerColor", more specifically cycle through the spectrum.
Is this possible? How would I obtain a reference to that memory address?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you can't change the value within this resource file.  That is the whole point of a resource file, having a static resource that does not change.

What you can do is have multiple definitions of different styles in this resource file, and change the style that is being applied to a layout element.

That can be done using [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view).

Hope that helps!