# How we add styles programmatically?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-styles

I have written one style for TextView and I set that one for my `TextView` as `style="@style/popup_window_text_style"` working fine, no issues.

Now I want that same style to do in programmatically for my textview

```
TextView textView = new TextView(mContext);
```

Is there any way to do it programmatically in Java?

My style in styles.xml

```
<style name="popup_window_text_style">
        <item name="android:layout_width">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">60dp</item>
        <item name="android:padding">10dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginLeft">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:layout_marginRight">1dp</item>
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ctxmenu_btn_selector</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/black</item>
        <item name="android:textStyle">bold</item>
        <item name="android:textSize">16sp</item>
        <item name="android:gravity">center_vertical</item>
        <item name="android:singleLine">true</item>
    </style>
```

Comment: [How to programmatically setting style attribute in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016344/593709)

Comment: @AdilSoomro So Generally we can't set styles programmatically right.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This should work for you:

```
textView.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.popup_window_text_style);
```

But note that some properties may not be affected and may have to be set manually [as specified in the Android developer docs](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).

Unfortunately the current SDK appears to lack any form of a setStyle() method.