# How to dynamically create a button and assign it a style defined in styles.xml?

Tags: android, user-interface

I need to dynamically create a styled button. I thought maybe I should do it like this:

```
XmlPullParser parser = m_context.getResources().getXml(R.style.Button_Plain);
buttonStyle = Xml.asAttributeSet(parser);
Button btn = new Button (m_context, buttonStyle);
```

But `getXml` throws exception "Requesting resource failed because it is complex". Is there any easy way to do what I need?

Comment: How we add styles progrmatically? http://stackoverflow.com/q/11507476/1012284

Comment: Does this question solve your problem?

[Set Style in Code][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use Following Constructor to create Button Object:

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/Button.html#Button(android.content.Context, android.util.AttributeSet, int)

```
public Button (Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle)
```

and pass following parameters:

```
Button btn = new Button (m_context, null, R.style.Button_Plain);
```

No need to use XmlPullParser.

Comment: Thank you! That page you've linked is the first place I looked, but it seems to lack descriptions for constructors.

Comment: you are welcome, yes, there is a no description at all for button class, but if you will look into View class Documentation, you will find enough.

Answer (score 0):

Its basically this:

`Button button = new Button(ContextActivity, null, R.style.whateverStyleYouHad);`