# Style appearances don't work

Tags: android

I'm working on a sort of progress screen but I'm having trouble with the appearances.

Here is my code:

```
    LinearLayout progressLayout = new LinearLayout(this);
    progressLayout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
    progressLayout.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    LayoutParams layoutParams = new LayoutParams(
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
            android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT);

    progressLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    LayoutParams titelParams = new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    titelParams.setMargins(0, 0, 0, pixelsToDIP(15));

    TextView t = new TextView(this);
    t.setText("Zorgdossier wordt geladen");
    t.setTextAppearance(this, android.R.attr.textAppearanceLarge);
    t.setLayoutParams(titelParams);

    ProgressBar circle = new ProgressBar(this);
    circle.setScrollBarStyle(android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
    circle.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, android.view.ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    progressLayout.addView(t);
    progressLayout.addView(circle);

    this.setContentView(progressLayout);

}

private int pixelsToDIP(int pixel) {
    float pixels = TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_DIP,
            pixel, this.getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

    return (int) pixels;
}
```

I set the style of the progress and textview to large but they display really small.
Any ideas?

Comment: How we add styles progrmatically  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11507476/1012284

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using the wrong function.

In fact you set the style in the constructor.

```
ProgressBar circle = new ProgressBar(this, null, 
                               android.R.attr.progressBarStyleLarge);
```