# Android styles and themes

Tags: java, android-layout, android

I create simple `style.xml` file

```
<style name="You.EditText.Style" parent="@android:style/Widget.EditText">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorRed</item>
    <item name="android:gravity">center</item>
</style>
```

But all `EditText`s I create dynamically. How I can declare my style to `EditText` attribute?

Comment: Sounds like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate your `EditText` view like this:

```
EditText e = new EditText(context, null, R.style.You_EditText_Style);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the EditText#setTextAppearance(context, resid) method.

Example:

```
myEditText.setTextAppearance(getApplicationContext(), R.style.id);
```

See [EditText reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setTextAppearance%28android.content.Context,%20int%29).