# Modify existing theme

Tags: android, styles, themes, android-theme

I would like to know if it is possible (and how) to customize an existing theme.

What I'm looking for is how can I retrieve a certain attribute (i.e. color) and change it when the `Activity` starts and reapply the modified theme before `setContentView()`.

Similar to `setTheme()`, but instead of using a resource id, use the modified theme.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on further research and Eric's comment there is not yet a possible way to modify a theme programmatically. Different themes can be applied programmatically but not modified. Once the style is set in XML, it cannot be modified.

Answer (score 6):

Why not just make your own theme, setting the `android:parent` to the theme you want to copy, then set your own attributes? That is demonstrated in [this documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html), like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CodeFont" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance.Medium">
        <item name="android:layout_width">fill_parent</item>
        <item name="android:layout_height">wrap_content</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#00FF00</item>
        <item name="android:typeface">monospace</item>
    </style>
</resources>
```

In this case, the `CodeFont` style will be identical to the `TextAppearance.Medium` style, except for the `item`s specified here. You can do the same with any theme, including the default Holo or Dark theme or whatnot.

Comment: Because I want to be able to change it every time the `Activity` starts using different input values. This way it's static. I've looked into it and tried it, but it's not what I want.

Comment: You cannot change a style programmatically, sorry. You [can modify the appearance of items based on a custom style](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view), but once the style is set in XML, it cannot be modified.

Comment: That also deals with preloaded styles. I'm looking for changing it while running.

Comment: Well, as I've already given you the skinny--you cannot change styles or edit them programmatically--that's as far as the answer will go. Good luck, I guess.