# Change colorControlActivated color programmatically

Tags: android, checkbox, switchcompat

I have read a few threads regarding the color, but all of them has to set via style.xml.

For now I'm using this to determine the color.

> ```
> <style name="Color1SwitchStyle">
>     <item name="colorControlActivated">#0e8488</item>
> </style>'
> ```

Is it possible to change the color of a SwitchCompat/Checkbox without using XML, for instance using code?

Comment: Do you had a look on this ? http://stackoverflow.com/a/27879897

Comment: yup, but I have no idea how to access the ColorStateList via code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/17788095

Comment: it shows how to create but SwitchCompat only can assign ColorStateList to BackgroundTintList & TextColor.

Comment: Seems that you cannot modify themes / styles programmatically: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12357768/modify-existing-theme http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view .  You may consider using a custom drawable for say the thumb of a switchcompat by using `setThumbResource()`, in which case the Tint manager will not tint it and you can apply color to it programmatically.

Comment: For now I'm using third party library which included the change color configuration, however I'm looking for more official way as 3rd party library won't get frequent updates.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Actually, it's not hard to do.

Example:

```
int[][] states = new int[][] {
        new int[] {-android.R.attr.state_checked},
        new int[] {android.R.attr.state_checked},
};

int[] thumbColors = new int[] {
        Color.BLACK,
        Color.RED,
};

int[] trackColors = new int[] {
        Color.GREEN,
        Color.BLUE,
};

SwitchCompat switchCompat = (SwitchCompat) findViewById(R.id.switchControl);
AppCompatCheckBox checkBox = (AppCompatCheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkbox);
checkBox.setSupportButtonTintList(new ColorStateList(states, thumbColors));
DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getThumbDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, thumbColors));
DrawableCompat.setTintList(DrawableCompat.wrap(switchCompat.getTrackDrawable()), new ColorStateList(states, trackColors));
```

Comment: Works like a charm!

Comment: that is absolutely perfect and clear answer

Answer (score 2):

```
    DrawableCompat.setTintList(switch.getThumbDrawable(), new ColorStateList(
            new int[][]{
                    new int[]{android.R.attr.state_checked},
                    new int[]{}
            },
            new int[]{
                    Color.parseColor("Write Color code-for ex #ffffffff"),
                    Color.GRAY
            }));
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please explain what you are doing along with the code, so others could also be benefitted.

Answer (score -1):

Another way to do, change the background color:

setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);

As:

```
holper.aSwitch.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked) {

            if (isChecked){

                buttonView.setBackgroundColor(android.graphics.Color.GREEN);
            }}
```