# change button background at runtime in android

Tags: android, android-button

I want to change my button background at RUNTIME

I know how to add a custom background to a button, but

- How can I change it to borderlessButtonStyle?
  in the xml was easy, I used:

  ```
  style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle")
  ```
- How can I switch back to the default background? The following is not what I want (apperantly it is not the default used in Jelly Bean)

  ```
  changeableButton.setBackgroundResource(android.R.drawable.btn_default);
  ```

  Thanks for your help

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I actually found a solution

You can save the initial background of your button in a Drawable object

```
Drawable d = button.getBackground();
```

Now you can modify your button's background as you wish

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.custom_button);
```

Than you can modify it back

```
button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

does this work?
`changeableButton.setBackground(null);`

Comment: Yeah I thought so already, I couldn't test it first. what about `bt.setBackgroundResource(0);`? still no background?

Comment: I googled a bit and I'm afraid this is not possible, what you actually want to do is remove the previous style applied in the XML. Styles can't be applied programmatically.. see
: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2016344/1323666 `Generally you can't change styles programmatically; you can set the look of a screen, or part of a layout, or individual button in your XML layout using themes or styles. Themes can, however, be applied programmatically.`

Comment: Ok, and what about the default background?

Comment: I just find the solution for the default background: Drawable d = b.getBackground(); than you can do this b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Comment: great! what is it? I'm sorry I couldn't help you

Comment: Drawable d = b.getBackground(); b.setBackgroundDrawable(d);

Comment: You should add this as an answer and mark it as answer. Then others looking for a solution to the same problem can be helped. I'm glad you found it yourself ;)

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple answer to this problem:

```
button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.backround);
```

you can also change back to your default backround by using an if statement and repeating the above statement by just changing the "backround" resource to your default resource.
Btw thanks for A2A.