# Coloring Buttons in Android with Material Design and AppCompat

Tags: android, button, android-view, android-button, material-design

Before the `AppCompat` update came out today I was able to change the color of buttons in Android L but not on older versions. After including the new AppCompat update I am unable to change the color for either version, when I do try the button just disappears. Does anyone know how to change the button color?

The following pictures shows what I want to achieve:

[image: picture showing desired result]

The white button is default, the red one is what I want.

This is what I was doing previously to change the color of the buttons in the `styles.xml`:

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">insert color here</item>
```

and to do it dynamically:

```
button.getBackground().setColorFilter(getResources().getColor(insert color here), PorterDuff.Mode.MULTIPLY);
```

Also I did change the theme parent from `@android:style/Theme.Material.Light.DarkActionBar` to `Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar`

Comment: I tried the same but nothing changed the color of the Button. I also removed android: from the attribute becouse it is from the support lib and not part of android namespace

Comment: If you are using android:colorButtonNormal with Android 5.0 it works - but it seems not to be backwards compatible

Comment: Yes that is exactly what I was experiencing

Comment: I also figured out that the accent color does not change the CheckBox color, but it does in older versions

Comment: plus one for that dynamic method. :)

Answer (score 225, accepted):

Officially fixed in Support Library rev.22 (Fri March 13, 2015). See relevant google code issue:

https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/37008632

**Usage example**

theme.xml:

```
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
```

v21/theme.xml

```
<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>
```

Comment: Is there any example how to use it? How can I set colors on just one Button?

Comment: I updated the answer with the attribute definitions that i use and know they work.

Comment: @WindRider I have a problem though, I want to use it to create buttons with different colors. I create styles Button.Red, Button.Green, all with parent equals Button base style. I set item colorButtonNormal to requested color, set this as button theme. Unfortunately it only colours buttons for 21. Below it does not override colorButtonNormal defined in theme.

Comment: What parent style do you use? Check that all your styles contain colorButtonNormal for <v21 and android:colorButtonNormal for v21. Looks like you only have the second defined. Just a give me a pastebin with your styles.

Comment: @WindRider Unfortunately I'm having the same issue. When applying theme directly to a button, like `<Button android:theme="@style/RedButton"... />`, the theme only gets applied for v21. (If I put the colors in the app-wide theme definitions, it works for all API levels, but I cant do that because I need buttons with different colors). Seems like a bug in appcompat to me.

Comment: @dominik4142 did you find a solution for this? (see my comment above)

Comment: Greg, shouldn't it be <Button style="@style/RedButton"... /> instead?

Comment: @WindRider you didn't mention me and I didn't get any notification.
This is what I found out:
In order for this styling to work, I need to set theme:= of the button. This works nicely on >21. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to bother lower versions. They are bothered only by settings colorButtonNormal in app theme. Because I want to achieve different button colors, your solution doesn't help me much.

Comment: @GregEnnis I totally agree, same for me. I worked it around by replacing button background on lower versions (this were very small contextual buttons used in one place so I could afford that). I simply used theme= and style= both on one button, theme to apply colouring on >21, style override in both <21 (background + margins) and >21 (empty to disable <21 background replacement).

Comment: @WindRider - no it should not.  android:theme is required here. As I mentioned, it works on v21, so that is not the problem. It sounds like you have it working - can you post a working sample?

Comment: Dont work for `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button` in `Compat 22.1.1`

Comment: With AppCompat 22.1.1 it works for me on 2.3.7, 4.4.4 and 5.1 too for one button only: setting button's 
`android:theme="@style/ColoredButton"`, 
and in styles.xml 
`<style name="ColoredButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_yellow</item>
</style>`

Comment: How do you change the text color (for example to white)?

Comment: @hunyadym, adding a theme to the button breaks onClick for some reason. I would classify this as a workaround until the Design library provides a better way.

Comment: @gladed: It seems in your case the problem is this bug: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62795#c1

Comment: @gladed I have the same issue. Did you manage to find a good workaround?

Comment: @gladed My current workaround is to set the OnClickListener programmatically.

Comment: @Rachel another way is to use AppCompatButton and programmatically set the background tint modes but this is very messy. The way you are doing it is probably the best we can do for now.

Comment: It is not working, the AppCompat library version is `22.2.0`

Comment: @hunyadym I can confirm it works just fine! The answer should be edited!

Comment: It helps only partially, setEnabled(false) no effect

Comment: If anyone looking for proof android are crazy, here it is! 3 hours and counting to change button color! Jesus Christ!

Answer (score 148):

## Edit (22.06.2016):

**Appcompat** library started to support material buttons after I posted the original response. [In this post](https://medium.com/@emrullahluleci/android-material-button-e7b92cb014e0) you can see the easiest implementation of raised and flat buttons.

## Original Answer:

Since that AppCompat doesn't support the button yet you can use xml as backgrounds. For doing that I had a look at the source code of the Android and found the related files for styling material buttons.

### 1 - Look at the original implementation of material button from source.

Have a look at the [btn_default_material.xml on android source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_material.xml).

You can copy the file into your projects drawable-v21 folder. But don't touch the color attr here. The file you need to change is the second file.

**drawable-v21/custom_btn.xml**

```
<ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape" />
</ripple>
```

### 2 - Get the shape of the original material button

As you realise there is a shape used inside this drawable which you can find in [this file of the source code](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/drawable/btn_default_mtrl_shape.xml).

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
   android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
   android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
   android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
<shape android:shape="rectangle">
    <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
    <solid android:color="?attr/colorButtonNormal" />
    <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
             android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
             android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
             android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
</shape>
```

### 3 - Getting dimensions of the material button

And in this file you there are some dimensions used from the file [that you can find here](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/res/res/values/dimens_material.xml). You can copy the whole file and put into your **values** folder. This is important for applying the same size (that is used in material buttons) to all buttons

### 4 - Create another drawable file for old versions

For older versions you should have another drawable with the same name. I am directly putting the items inline instead of referencing. You may want to reference them. But again, the most important thing is the original dimensions of the material button.

**drawable/custom_btn.xml**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    
    <!-- pressed state -->
    <item android:state_pressed="true">
        <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
            android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
                <solid android:color="@color/PRESSED_STATE_COLOR" />
                <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
    
    <!-- focused state -->
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
            android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
                <solid android:color="@color/FOCUSED_STATE_COLOR" />
                <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
    
    <!-- normal state -->
    <item>
        <inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:insetLeft="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetTop="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material"
            android:insetRight="@dimen/button_inset_horizontal_material"
            android:insetBottom="@dimen/button_inset_vertical_material">
            <shape android:shape="rectangle">
                <corners android:radius="@dimen/control_corner_material" />
                <solid android:color="@color/NORMAL_STATE_COLOR" />
                <padding android:left="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:top="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material"
                    android:right="@dimen/button_padding_horizontal_material"
                    android:bottom="@dimen/button_padding_vertical_material" />
            </shape>
        </inset>
    </item>
</selector>
```

## Result

Your button will have ripple effect on Lollipop devices. The old versions will have exactly same button except the ripple effect. But since that you provide drawables for different states, they'll also respond to touch events (as the old way).

Comment: So after implementing this, we just add `android:background="@drawable/custom_btn"` to our button?

Comment: Yes exactly. If you use the same background for all buttons and if you don't want to add this again and again, define a button style in your styles.xml

    **<style name="ButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Button">
         <item name="android:background">@drawable/custom_btn</item>
    </style>**

and add button style in your theme 
**<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonStyle</item>**

Comment: how can i add elevation to this button on pre-21? as i understand i should add new shape with shadow below button, but where exactly i should put it?

Comment: the shadow should be added to drawables for each state. ex: 
<!-- pressed state -->
<item android:state_pressed="true">
<!-- include the drawable that contains shadow -->
</item>

Comment: Very annoying that this isn't supported out of the box

Comment: I totally agree with you. Button is the mostly used widget but it is not included in the support library for material. I wonder what they were thinking.

Comment: It's unclear to me how to set the color for a single instance of the button. For example, I want most of my buttons to just be the standard grey, but a specific button to be red. Setting `colorButtonNormal` in the main theme will obviously make all buttons red, but when I try to include `colorButtonNormal="@color/red"` in the style which the button uses, this is ignored. What is the correct way to do this? I don't think having a different `btn_default_mtrl_shape` file for each color you may use is practical...

Comment: Also, following your guide it seems that the background isn't showing up at all...

Comment: I ended up getting it to work, the guide is fine. At step 2, you might want to hardcode the color resource directly into the shape's solid color instead of relying on a ?attr. I was trying to use a value from ?attr but was doing it wrong.

Comment: Has anyone else noticed the drop shadow effect disappears when using a `shape` drawable in the `ripple` but not if you set a colour directly?

Comment: This solution works fine, but the problem is when you need more buttons with different colors, then you have to create ripples and shapes for each button, which is quite annoying..

Answer (score 112):

This has been enhanced in v23.0.0 of AppCompat library
with the addition of more themes including

> Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored

First of all include appCompat dependency if you haven't already

```
compile('com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0') {
    exclude group: 'com.google.android', module: 'support-v4'
}
```

now since you need to use v23 of the app compat, you'll need to target SDK-v23 as well!

```
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    targetSdkVersion = 23
```

In your `values/theme`

```
<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/BrandButtonStyle</item>
```

In your `values/style`

```
<style name="BrandButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/yourButtonColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

In your `values-v21/style`

```
<style name="BrandButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/yourButtonColor</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/White</item>
</style>
```

Since your button theme is based on `Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored` The text color on the button is by default white!

but it seems there is an issue when you disable the button, the button will change its color to light grey, but the text color will remain white!

a workaround for this is to specifically set the text color on the button to white!
as I have done in the style shown above.

now you can simply define your button and let AppCompat do the rest :)

```
<Button
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="48dp" />
```

Disabled State
[image: Disabled state]

Enabled State
[image: Enabled State]

Edit:

To add `<Button android:theme="@style/BrandButtonStyle"/>`

Comment: That's the best way to do it, now! You can also use the style on individual buttons with `<Button android:theme="@style/BrandButtonStyle"/>`. It has to be the `theme` attribute and _not_ the `style` attribute.

Comment: @Muhammad Alfaifi Do you have sample project or gist for this? I've created clean project and it does not work: https://github.com/Bresiu/ThemeTest. In Lolipop button colors with accent color and on API v16, button remains gray: http://i.imgur.com/EVwkpk2.png

Comment: It helps only partially, setEnabled(false) no effect

Comment: This only worked fro me when specifying the attribute android:theme. I could not get the attribute style to work for me with the button tag.

Comment: Using v23.1 lib, this did not work correctly, it always showed the accent color as bg, not the one defined, when trying to set it to the whole theme

Comment: I confirm this does not work for the whole theme for API < 21, it works when assigning the theme to the button though

Comment: Same issue here on , on v23.1 the disabled button is the same colour as the enabled button. very frustrating. anyone figure this out?

Comment: This approach worked for me , v23.1.1 https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=176472

Comment: From AppCompatButton javadoc: _"This will automatically be used when you use {@link android.widget.Button} in your
 * layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views."_ So you dont have to manualy specify `<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton />` just use `<Button android:theme="@style/BrandButtonStyle"/>`

Comment: @Semanticer thanks for noticing and you are right, old answer forgot to edit that :)

Comment: This along with TouchBoarder's answer helped me set the button color and text color in Java using: `ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(your_colored_button,
 ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),R.color.your_custom_color));`

Comment: `Error:(3732, 21) No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'textColor'.` ... the subtle difference in the values/style and values-v21/style shows you what we're up against in the Android world.

Comment: using this method I see the lifting (shadow) effect, but not the ripple ...

Answer (score 65):

In Android Support Library 22.1.0, Google made the `Button` tint aware.
So, another way to customise the background color of button is to use the `backgroundTint` attribute.

For example,

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/add_remove_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:backgroundTint="@color/bg_remove_btn_default"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       tools:text="Remove" />
```

Comment: Finally! Blog post about the 22.1 release: http://android-developers.blogspot.no/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html

Comment: Documentation says: "This will automatically be used when you use Button in your layouts. You should only need to manually use this class when writing custom views." http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html does this mean we don't have to manually change all of our layouts and java code?

Comment: @Stephane no, we should change layouts. https://chris.banes.me/2015/04/22/support-libraries-v22-1-0/

Comment: AWESOME! Now, is there a AppCompatToggleButton that lets you change the background of ToggleButtons? Maybe I can plagiarize the code...

Comment: Android Support Library 22.1.1 has been released. A changelog is pending.

Comment: Unfortunately this works only on API 21+. The android:backgroundTint attribute doesn't work on pre-Lollipop even with AppCompat library. Only colorButtonNormal from theme works on pre-Lollipop.

Comment: This plus the link to the blog post is the answer. @mail929 it would be great if you could update the answer as such.

Answer (score 43):

To support colored buttons use the latest AppCompat library (>**23.2.1**) with:

> inflate - XML

AppCompat Widget:

```
android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
```

AppCompat Style:

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```

**NB!** To set a custom color in xml: use the attr: `app` instead of `android`

(use `alt+enter` or declare `xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"` to use `app`)

**app**:backgroundTint="@color/your_custom_color"

Example:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/your_custom_color"
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"     
     android:text="Colored Button"/>
```

> **or** set it programmatically - JAVA

```
 ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(your_colored_button,
 ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),R.color.your_custom_color));
```

Comment: Your Java code worked for me. And Muhammad Alfaifi answer helped set the text color of the button.

Comment: is there an easy way to programmatically set the tint (not background)?

Comment: Wonderful! Works on 4.4.4 as well! And selector state is also maintained quite well!

Comment: [Per the docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/AppCompatButton.html): This is automatically used when setting buttons in your layouts. You only need to specify AppCompatButton when creating custom views.

Comment: Interestingly the XML changes worked perfectly in a fragment but not in an Activity layout. The Activity buttons used colorAccent only. The programmatic version worked though.

Answer (score 25):

With latest Support Library you could just inherit you activity from `AppCompatActivity`, so it will inflate your `Button` as `AppCompatButton` and give you an opportunity to style color of every single button on the layout with using of `android:theme="@style/SomeButtonStyle"`, where `SomeButtonStyle` is:

```
<style name="SomeButtonStyle" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/example_color</item>
</style>
```

Worked for me in 2.3.7, 4.4.1, 5.0.2

Comment: Thanks!!! I just changed the parent value for "Widget.AppCompat.EditText" as I need to update the EditText style.

Comment: Thank you, worked for me as well. Make sure to use `android:theme` and not `style`. You can also add `colorControlHighlight` and `colorControlActivated`.

Comment: does't work, API 22, AppCompatActivity, theme Material.Light

Comment: @AndreyUglev try to use `Theme.AppCompat.Light` instead.

Comment: Hi, it changes the desired color BUT removes the shadows.

Comment: Hi again, I can see. It's proper behaviour now.

Comment: This is the simplest solution I think, this worked fine for android 4.2.2, 5.0 and others.

Comment: I was using Activity instead of AppCompatActivity because of that button color didn't change.

Answer (score 16):

if you want below style

[image]

add this style your button

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored"
```

if you want this style

[image]

add below code

```
style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
```

Comment: `compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.0'` You must have to add.

Comment: but the question is how to have material buttons with different colors, so that not all have the primary color of the theme.

Answer (score 15):

The answer is in **THEME** not style

The problem is that the Button color is stick to the colorButtonNormal of the theme. I have tried to change the Style in many different ways with no luck. **So I changed the button theme**.

Create a theme with colorButtonNormal and colorPrimary:

```
<style name="ThemeAwesomeButtonColor" parent="AppTheme">
    <item name="colorPrimary">@color/awesomePrimaryColor</item>
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/awesomeButtonColor</item>
</style>
```

Use this theme in button

```
<Button
        android:id="@+id/btn_awesome"
        style="@style/AppTheme.Button"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeAwesomeButtonColor"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/btn_awesome"/>
```

The "AppTheme.Button" can be any thing extends Button style like here I use primary color for text color:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    ...
    <item name="android:textColor">?attr/colorPrimary</item>
    ...
</style>
```

And you get the button in any color you want that compatible to material design.

Comment: what are other attributes i can add into styles .

Answer (score 4):

I've just created an android library, that allows you to easily modify the button color and the ripple color

https://github.com/xgc1986/RippleButton

```
<com.xgc1986.ripplebutton.widget.RippleButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/btn"
    android:text="Android button modified in layout"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    app:buttonColor="@android:color/black"
    app:rippleColor="@android:color/white"/>
```

You don't need to create an style for every button you want wit a different color, allowing you to customize the colors randomly

Answer (score 4):

this work for me with appcompat-v7:22.2.0 in android + 4.0

in your styles.xml

```
<style name="Button.Tinted" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">YOUR_TINT_COLOR</item>
    <item name="colorControlHighlight">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

in your layout file

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/but_next"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/but_continue"
    android:theme="@style/Button.Tinted" />
```

Comment: Hi, it changes the desired color BUT removes the shadows.

Comment: Hi again, I can see. It's proper behaviour now.

Comment: How can you do this in Java?

Comment: @MicroR check the  answer above.

Answer (score 4):

**Layout:**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
  style="@style/MyButton"
  ...
  />
```

**styles.xml:**

```
<style name="MyButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
  <item name="backgroundTint">@color/button_background_selector</item>
  <item name="android:textColor">@color/button_text_selector</item>
</style>
```

**color/button_background_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#555555"/>
    <item android:color="#00ff00"/>
</selector>
```

**color/button_text_selector.xml:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_enabled="false" android:color="#888888"/>
    <item android:color="#ffffff"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 3):

For those using an `ImageButton` here is how you do it:

In style.xml:

```
<style name="BlueImageButton" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

in v21/style.xml:

```
<style name="BlueImageButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.ImageButton">
    <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/primary</item>
    <item name="android:tint">@color/white</item>
</style>
```

Then in your layout file:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageButton
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:theme="@style/BlueImageButton"
    android:layout_width="42dp"
    android:layout_height="42dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_check_black_24dp"
    />
```

Comment: This helped....I guess it is important to note to apply the button style as a theme instead of a style in the Button widget. I was applying it under style="@style/BlueImageButton" and it didn't work

Answer (score 3):

If you use style solution with *colorButtonNormal*, don't forget to inherit from **Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored** so the ripple effect is working ;)

Like

```
<style name="CustomButtonStyle" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
      <item name="colorButtonNormal">@android:color/white</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 2):

Another simple solution using the AppCompatButton

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
     android:layout_width="wrap_content"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
     app:backgroundTint="@color/red"
     android:text="UNINSTALL" />
```

Answer (score 2):

I use this. Ripple effect and button click shadow working.

style.xml

```
<style name="Button.Red" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/material_white</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundTint">@color/red</item>
</style>
```

Button on layout:

```
<Button
        style="@style/Button.Red"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/close"/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
android:backgroundTint="@color/customColor"
```

Or even :

```
android:background="@color/customColor"
```

and that will give custom color to the button.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want "Flat" material button, you can customize their background using [selectableItemBackground](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr.html#selectableItemBackground) attribute as explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27932664/2358786).

Comment: If you don't want to change any of the "tint" colors or selected colors this is definitely an easy solution to still get a feedback with colored buttons.  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

To change the color of a single button

```
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, getResources().getColorStateList(R.color.colorId));
```

Answer (score 1):

For me, the problem was that in Android 5.0 the `android:colorButtonNormal` had no effect, and actually, no item from the theme (like `android:colorAccent`), but in Android 4.4.3, for example, did. The project was configured with `compileSdkVersion` and `targetSdkVersion` to 22, so I've made all the changes as @Muhammad Alfaifi sugessted, but in the end, I've noticed that the problem was the **buildToolsVersion**, that wasn't updated. Once I changed to **23.0.1**, everything start working almost as normal. Now, the `android:colorButtonNormal` still has no effect, but at least the button reacts to `android:colorAccent`, which for me is acceptable.

I hope that this hint could help someone.
Note: I've applied the style directly to the button, since the button's `android:theme=[...]` also didn't have effect.

Comment: You almost found the 100% correct way how to use new @style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored ;) - see this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/a/35811157/19733911

Answer (score 1):

One way to pull this off allows you to just point to a style and NOT theme ALL the buttons in your app the same.
In themes.xml add a theme

```
    <style name="Theme.MyApp.Button.Primary.Blue" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/someColor</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/white</item>
    </style>
```

Now in styles.xml add

```
    <style name="MyApp.Button.Primary.Blue" parent="">
        <item name="android:theme">@style/Theme.MyApp.Button.Primary.Blue</item>
    </style>
```

Now in your layout simply point to the STYLE in your Button

```
    <Button
        ...
        style="@style/MyApp.Button.Primary.Blue"
        ...  />
```

Answer (score 1):

### UPDATE

Use **design support library(23.2.0)** and **appcompatwidgets**  as below

**[In Android Support Library 22.1](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html)** :

> This is done automatically when inflating layouts - replacing Button
>   with AppCompatButton, TextView with AppCompatTextView, etc. to ensure
>   that each could support tinting. In this release, those tint aware
>   widgets are now publicly available, allowing you to keep tinting
>   support even if you need to subclass one of the supported widgets.

The full list of tint aware widgets:

```
AppCompatAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatButton
AppCompatCheckBox
AppCompatCheckedTextView
AppCompatEditText
AppCompatMultiAutoCompleteTextView
AppCompatRadioButton
AppCompatRatingBar
AppCompatSpinner
AppCompatTextView
```

**[Material Design for Pre-Lollipop Devices](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2014/10/appcompat-v21-material-design-for-pre.html)** :

> AppCompat (aka ActionBarCompat) started out as a backport of the
>   Android 4.0 ActionBar API for devices running on Gingerbread,
>   providing a common API layer on top of the backported implementation
>   and the framework implementation. AppCompat v21 delivers an API and
>   feature-set that is up-to-date with Android 5.0

---

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use AppCompat style like **Widget.AppCompat.Button** , **Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored**, etc., you need to use these styles with compatible views from support library.

Code below does not work for pre-lolipop devices:

```
<Button
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button" />
```

You need to use AppCompatButton to enabled AppCompat styles:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
   android:layout_width="wrap_content"
   android:layout_height="wrap_content"
   android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button" />
```

Comment: Aren't app compat widgets used automatically when inflating XML layouts? I believe `ImageView` gets replaced with `AppCompatImageView` and it should be the same with all widgets, that have corresponding `AppCompat` version.

Comment: Nope, If you don't target last target version, you need to define `android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView` explicitly.

Comment: What do you mean by `last target version`, @power?

Answer (score 0):

I actually didn't want a change to my custom button styles but unfortunately they weren't working anymore.

My App has a minSdkVersion of 9 and everything worked before.

I don't know why but since I removed the android: before the buttonStyle it seems to work again

now = working:

`<item name="buttonStyle">@style/ButtonmyTime</item>`

before = just gray material buttons:

`<item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonmyTime</item>`

I have no spezial folder for newver android version since my buttons are quite flat and they should look the same across all android versions.

Maybe someone can tell me why I had to remove the "android:"
The ImageButton is still working with "android:"

```
<item name="android:imageButtonStyle">@style/ImageButtonmyTimeGreen</item>
```

Answer (score 0):

After 2 days looking for answers, the button theming didn't work for me in API < 21.

My only solution is to override AppCompatButton  tinting not only with the base app theme "colorButtonNormal" but also the view backgroundTint like this :

```
public class AppCompatColorButton extends AppCompatButton {

    public AppCompatColorButton(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public AppCompatColorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.buttonStyle);
    }

    public AppCompatColorButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);

        if (TintManager.SHOULD_BE_USED) {
            setSupportBackgroundTintList(createButtonColorStateList(getContext(), attrs, defStyleAttr));
        }
    }

    static final int[] DISABLED_STATE_SET = new int[]{-android.R.attr.state_enabled};
    static final int[] FOCUSED_STATE_SET = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_focused};
    static final int[] PRESSED_STATE_SET = new int[]{android.R.attr.state_pressed};
    static final int[] EMPTY_STATE_SET = new int[0];

    private ColorStateList createButtonColorStateList(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        final int[][] states = new int[4][];
        final int[] colors = new int[4];
        int i = 0;

        final int themeColorButtonNormal = ThemeUtils.getThemeAttrColor(context, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorButtonNormal);
        /*TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, new int[] { android.R.attr.backgroundTint }, defStyleAttr, 0);
        final int colorButtonNormal = a.getColor(0, themeColorButtonNormal);*/
        TypedArray a = context.obtainStyledAttributes(attrs, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.View, defStyleAttr, 0);
        final int colorButtonNormal = a.getColor(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.styleable.View_backgroundTint, themeColorButtonNormal);
        a.recycle();
        final int colorControlHighlight = ThemeUtils.getThemeAttrColor(context, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorControlHighlight);

        // Disabled state
        states[i] = DISABLED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = ThemeUtils.getDisabledThemeAttrColor(context, android.support.v7.appcompat.R.attr.colorButtonNormal);
        i++;

        states[i] = PRESSED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = ColorUtils.compositeColors(colorControlHighlight, colorButtonNormal);
        i++;

        states[i] = FOCUSED_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = ColorUtils.compositeColors(colorControlHighlight, colorButtonNormal);
        i++;

        // Default enabled state
        states[i] = EMPTY_STATE_SET;
        colors[i] = colorButtonNormal;
        i++;

        return new ColorStateList(states, colors);
    }
}
```

You can then define your Button color like this :

```
<com.example.views.AppCompatColorButton
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:backgroundTint="#ffff0000"
            app:backgroundTint="#ffff0000"
            android:text="Button"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Answer (score 0):

This SO answer helped me arrive at an answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/30277424/3075340

I use this utility method to set the background tint of a button. It works with pre-lollipop devices:

```
// Set button background tint programmatically so it is compatible with pre-lollipop devices.
public static void setButtonBackgroundTintAppCompat(Button button, ColorStateList colorStateList){
    Drawable d = button.getBackground();
    if (button instanceof AppCompatButton) {
        // appcompat button replaces tint of its drawable background
        ((AppCompatButton)button).setSupportBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
    } else if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
        // Lollipop button replaces tint of its drawable background
        // however it is not equal to d.setTintList(c)
        button.setBackgroundTintList(colorStateList);
    } else {
        // this should only happen if
        // * manually creating a Button instead of AppCompatButton
        // * LayoutInflater did not translate a Button to AppCompatButton
        d = DrawableCompat.wrap(d);
        DrawableCompat.setTintList(d, colorStateList);
        button.setBackgroundDrawable(d);
    }

}
```

How to use in code:

```
Utility.setButtonBackgroundTintAppCompat(myButton,
ContextCompat.getColorStateList(mContext, R.color.your_custom_color));
```

This way, you do not have to specify a ColorStateList if you just want to change the background tint and nothing more but maintain the pretty button effects and what not.

Answer (score 0):

I set `android:textColor` to `@null` in my button theme and it helps.

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="Button.Base.Borderless" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Borderless.Colored">
    <item name="android:textColor">@null</item>
</style>
```

**some_layout.xml**

```
<Button
    style="@style/Button.Base.Borderless"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hint" />
```

Now button text color is `colorAccent` defined in `AppTheme`

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/colorAccent</item>
    <item name="borderlessButtonStyle">@style/Button.Base.Borderless</item>
    <item name="alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialog</item>
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do this via code in any color use this:

```
DrawableCompat.setTintList(button.getBackground(), ColorStateList.valueOf(yourColor));
```

Answer (score 0):

In my case, instead of using Button, I use androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton
and it worked for me.