# AppCompat v22.1.1 button style api 16+

Tags: android, android-support-library

I'm trying to style the buttons with the new supportv7 v22.1.1

It works fine on device with Lollipop, but on older device, it doesn't apply the theme anymore.

The themes.xml

```
<resources>

    <!-- Base application theme. -->
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/Button</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Button" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
        <item name="android:textColor">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:background">#1FA561</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

the manifest does include `android:theme="@style/AppTheme"`

Basic layout file

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".LoginActivity">

    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/login_form"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/email_login_form"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/email_sign_in_button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/action_sign_in"
                android:textStyle="bold" />

        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

</LinearLayout>
```

[image: Nexus 4 on 4.4.4]

Answer (score 0):

sorry to say this but, BUTTON style support not included in `appcompat-v7`

still want solution check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27505229/1168654) and you can also use any [third party library](https://github.com/navasmdc/MaterialDesignLibrary) for material button style

Comment: Thing is, it used to work, and then it stops, anyway i'm applying the theme on all button, it sucks, but it was simplest solution