# How to customize AppCompatButton color

Tags: android, android-appcompat, material-design

I saw new appCompat controls are available [here](http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2015/04/android-support-library-221.html). And implemented it in android app, but I don't find any specific way of customizing its color.

Just like if we set **accent color** in style, the edit text automatically catches it. But it is not working in case of AppCompatButton.

Does anybody find something regarding this?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

See here: [Coloring Buttons in Android with Material Design and AppCompat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat)

To summarize, you can use the `tintBackground` attribute on the button itself or you can use `colorControlNormal` (or a combination).

Also, you can just use `Button` and it'll get converted to an `AppCompatButton` as long as you're using the theme and inheriting from `AppCompatActivity` correctly.

**Examples from the linked URL**

theme.xml:

`<item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>`

v21/theme.xml

`<item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/button_color</item>`

or

```
<Button
       android:id="@+id/add_remove_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:backgroundTint="@color/bg_remove_btn_default"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       tools:text="Remove" />
```

Comment: A simple answer for a big problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 10):

Use the SupportLib with AppCompatButton like this:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton
       android:id="@+id/add_remove_button"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/bg_remove_btn_default"
       android:textColor="@android:color/white"
       tools:text="Remove" />
```

***app*** is a mxlns: xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"

so the backgroundTint works also for preLollipop