# Way to style layout to look like a button via using AppCompat v22

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-styles, android-appcompat

I would like to use `AppCompat v22` to style my `LinearLayout` so that it looked like button. I set its style like this:

```
<LinearLayout style="@style/Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button"
....
</LinearLayout>
```

and in app theme I have: `colorButtonNormal` property set.

After styling `LinearLayout` looks like button on devices running Lollipop but not on older versions.

Question is - what needs to be set to make `LinearLayout` look like button on older Android versions too by using `AppCompat v22`?

Comment: Check out : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat

Comment: @HareshChhelana I think I have different problem. My buttons work fine on all platforms but I want to style LinearLayout (or any other layout) without writing selectors. I want AppCompat to take care of this.

Answer (score 0):

To customize your LinearLayout set `android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"`
 in your layout.

```
<LinearLayout
    ......
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
    ......
    />
```

And define your style

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    ........
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
    ........
</style>
```

Comment: You are basically suggesting to use `android:theme` instead of `style`. The outcome is the same: white button-shaped rectangle on Android prior to L. `colorButtonNormal` property is not picked.

Answer (score 0):

```
<LinearLayout
......
android:theme="@style/AppTheme.Button"
......
/>
```

Define the style:

```
<style name="AppTheme.Button" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    ........
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/my_color</item>
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/my_color</item>
    ........
</style>
```