# Cant change colorButtonNormal value to all buttons

Tags: android, android-5.0-lollipop, android-4.4-kitkat, android-styles

I am trying to make all buttons in my app have default color using `colorButtonNormal` in my style.

It works nice on API 21 and above but under API 21 it only changes the background of some buttons and i dont know what is going wrong.

styles.xml

```
<resources xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_login</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/btn_login</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

v21/styles.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/white</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
        <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_login</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
    </style>



    <style name="AlertDialogCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimary">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="colorPrimaryDark">@color/bg_login</item>
    </style>

    <style name="Preference" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:colorPrimary">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="android:colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
        <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
        <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
        <item name="android:alertDialogTheme">@style/AlertDialogCustom</item>
        <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
    </style>



        <style name="EditTextThemeCustom" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
            <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
            <item name="android:editTextColor">@color/black</item>
            <item name="android:textColor">@color/black</item>
            <item name="colorAccent">@color/btn_login</item>
        </style>


</resources>
```

Result:

[Lollipop](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OuAjt.png)

and

[Kitkat](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MXXWm.png)

Any suggestions?

Comment: [Response](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat)

Comment: i have the same code as the accepted answer...can you elaborate?

Answer (score 3):

Add to your `styles.xml`

```
<style name="ColoredButton" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/btn_login</item>
</style>
```

and then use

```
android:theme="@style/ColoredButton"
```

as one of your buttons' attributes

Comment: This doesn't work for me, however if I add other properties to ColoredButton they do work (i.e. text color)

Comment: `Widget.AppCopmat.Button` is a *style* not a *theme*. A theme overlay such as `<style name="ColoredButton" parent="">` would produce desired effect without any unpredictable side effects.

Answer (score 2):

The buttons you inflate will get automatically translated to `AppCompatButton`.

Wherever you have `new Button(context)` you need to use `new AppCompatButton(context)` instead for Material theme colors to apply.

Comment: its ok i fixed it. i had style="?android:attr/buttonSizeSmall" something like that so when i removed it everything was fixed

Comment: With appcompat themes you'd use `?buttonStyleSmall` instead of `?android:buttonStyleSmall`. Please post it as a solution or delete the question.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this issue in old devices(<21) because, my activity was extending just activity when I make in it extend AppCompatActivity, in old devices also it is working perfect.