# How to create custom Button with using AppCompat library?

Tags: android, android-custom-view, android-appcompat

Is it possible to extend Button class without loosing AppCompat features like coloring/tinting/shadows?

For now, if I create custom class which extends Button and use it in layout it becomes white background/black foreground.

Comment: Is this what you are looking for? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat

Comment: You could start with this api: https://github.com/Clans/FloatingActionButton Have a look how he has created a floating button custom using AppCompoact Library

Comment: @Rohit5k2 - no I am not looking for coloring with styles, but I need some custom button with all render features of AppCompatButton.

Comment: @zIronManbox - your button is fully overwrites drawing of button buy I need only to add some logic in class without touching rendering.

Comment: @curioushikhov What kind of logic. If so, you could extend the already available Button component which is using AppCompact, and use this as a  view into your Layout.

Comment: Lear more about creating custom components, I think that's what you are looking at.

Comment: FYI:http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/create-view.html

http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html

Comment: @zIronManBox I know how to build custom views, there is problem because  AppCompat library uses custom inflater which converts button tag in layout to AppCompatButton instance. It doesn't recognize any subclasses of Button or AppCompatButton classes and because of this it looses theming.

Comment: I think, then you would have to use the styling xmls for your custom view class. I guess, when your custom class gets extended, the BaseStyle xml is lost, I think you would have to apply or redefine baseStyle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example custom button:

```
package me.shikhov.buttontest;

import android.content.Context;
import android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton;
import android.util.AttributeSet;

/**
 * Created by andrew on 19.01.16.
 */
public class MyButton extends
        AppCompatButton
{
    public MyButton(Context context) {
         this(context, null);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        this(context, attrs, 0);
    }

    public MyButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyleAttr) {
        super(context, attrs, defStyleAttr);
    }
}
```

Example layout:

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="me.shikhov.buttontest.MainActivity">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="TEST BUTTON"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:id="@+id/standard_button"
            />

        <me.shikhov.buttontest.MyButton
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
                android:text="MY BUTTON TEST"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_below="@id/standard_button"
                />

</RelativeLayout>
```

**Important notes:**

1. MyButton should extend `AppCompatButton` and **not** `android.view.Button`
2. You should **explicitly** set `android:theme`. That theme should be derived from `Widget.AppCompat.Button` theme.

Comment: What is the logic behind (2)? I've never done it because extending from the class inherits.