# How to tint Button using the Latest AppCompat

Tags: android, android-button, android-appcompat

I need to know what is the best (and recommented) way to tint a Material Button (AppCompatButton) using the latest AppCompat (23.2.1 for the time being). I could have never imagined that it would be so frustrating! I tried most of the answers from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat) but either they wouldn't work or worked with unexpected results.

I need to keep backwards compatibility to api >= 9 And just need the ripple effect to be applied to >=21 nothing fancy. So what is the best way so far?

I'd appreciate if you could provide both xml and java code.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are many ways to do that.
My favorite is the following:

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/activity_main_some_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored"
 android:text="This is a button" />
```

This automatically tints the button with the accent color you (hopefully) set in your theme, while maintaining pressed states at API < Lollipop and Ripple >= Lollipop.

If nothing else works you could just tint the button yourself:

```
AppCompatButton myExampleButton = new AppCompatButton(getContext());

myExampleButton.setSupportBackgroundTintList(ContextCompat.getColorStateList(getContext(),
                                             R.color.some_color));
```

**Update**

You can do the following to use a self defined color:

```
<style name="MyButtonTheme" parent="Widget.AppCompat.Button.Colored">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/someColor</item>
</style>
```

Define a new style with the desired color.

```
<Button
 android:id="@+id/activity_main_some_button"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:theme="@style/MyButtonTheme"
 android:text="This is a button" />
```

Set it to your button.

Comment: I don't want to use the accent color. Just some arbitrary color. How can this be done from xml?