# Customize Button (ANDROID)

Tags: android, android-layout, button, material-design

**I want to fully customize button in android, with keeping all its juicy material design styles.**

- Without a custom drawable png for button, just applying a color to button, i am able to change the color of the button and keep the *Elevation, Ripple Effect, Rounded corner* and it looks nice.
- The code i used for this is

  ```
  <resources>

      <style name="AppTheme.NoActionBar">
          <item name="android:colorButtonNormal">#8126f3</item>
      </style>
  </resources>
  ```
- Then i wanted to put my own drawable into the button and keep the Material Design effects . so i created a drawable (V21) and assigned it as background to the button.

  **button_ripple.xml**

  ```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <ripple xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:color="?attr/colorControlHighlight">
  <item android:drawable="@drawable/take_ride_map_btn"/>
  </ripple>
  ```
- But now the problem is that it does not have a elevation. And the ripple effect does not start at the point of touch.

*I have looked into [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26686250/material-effect-on-button-with-background-color), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26346727/android-material-design-button-styles) SO Question but these are not helpful with using the custom drawable into button.*

*Please do suggest how can i achieve this -*

- Elevation while having the custom drawable.
- Start the Ripple Effect at the point where user touches.

Answer (score 0):

you can always have the elevation if you set the button to wrap_content both ways i.e height and width and for the ripple effect you should use [RippleDecoratorView](https://github.com/thomsonreuters/RippleDecoratorView).

You don't need to cast it to anything just wrap the button inside it in `xml` and your good to go, plus its highly customizeable too

Comment: just go to this [link](https://github.com/thomsonreuters/RippleDecoratorView) , you will find the usage in details there there :)