# Button colorButtonNormal style not working in pre-Lollipop devices

Tags: android, android-layout, android-theme, android-styles, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using this trick to change the background color of all the application buttons:

```
<style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/unpressed2</item>
</style>
```

It's working perfectly in post-Lollipop (api 21) devices but in pre-Lollipop it's being ignored.

How can I change the background color of the buttons also in pre-Lollipop devices?

Comment: How you're applying it?

Comment: try giving `android:colorButtonNormal` also

Comment: @RahulKhurana I'm applying it simply with the code I attached in the question. And android:colorButtonNormal does not exist below api 21, android: must be used only if you are above api 21.

Comment: You might want to check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat#comment47930599_29053700

Comment: Do these devices still exist?

Comment: @RahulKhurana tryed all the solutions in that post and also the solution of that comment you linked me. None of them worked.

Comment: @NullPointerException Have you tried applying it to individual View as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/37127051/4079010

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes, I tryed. It seems that adding implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0' is not transforming all my Buttons in android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton. Why? If i forze to be android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton instead of Button some solutions works. But it's very rare, because It's supposed that just adding that line in grafle file will transform all the buttons in appcompatbuttons but it's not happening. why?

Comment: @NullPointerException As mentioned in the last link are you using `android:theme` with android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton?

Comment: @RahulKhurana yes, tryed it, the solutions only works if I forze to use android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatButton instead of just Button. Please, can you answer my question from the previous comment? I think that understanding that is the key for solve this problem

Comment: @NullPointerException If you want to use it with button see here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat#comment52579555_32238489

Comment: @NullPointerException about why it is not working because it is not supported: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519979/coloring-buttons-in-android-with-material-design-and-appcompat#comment44433226_27505229

Comment: thank you very much, @RahulKhurana it worked changing the activity to AppCompatActivity. Please can you post an answer? if not, I will post the answer, but other persons can find this problem too

Comment: @NullPointerException posted it as answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want your `Button` to work with `colorButtonNormal` your activity needs to extend `AppCompatActivity`