# Set theme for AppCompatButton programmatically

Tags: android, android-support-library, android-appcompat

I have a button that have two state and must have different background for each of them.

For using advantage of android default implement of Button (for example ripple effect in +Lollipop) i didn't define custom background and using `colorButtonNormal` attribute as below :

```
<style name="PrimaryButton.Success">
  <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorSuccess</item>
</style>

<style name="PrimaryButton.Fail">
  <item name="colorButtonNormal">@color/colorFail</item>
</style>
```

I know how to set theme for my button when using XML(setting `app:theme` attribute of my `AppCompatButton`) but as i mention above,I need change it on run-time programmatically. how can i do it ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to programmatically setting style attribute in a view](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2016249/how-to-programmatically-setting-style-attribute-in-a-view)

Comment: @MojtabaAsg Are you sure you want to change the theme? Why not set the color of the button to a [Color State List](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/color-list-resource.html)?

Comment: @cricket_007 no my question is about new attribute added to appcompatbutton and not legacy style !

Comment: @Bryan let me know your approach, can i define custom state and change state with your solution ?

Answer (score 4):

If you only need one color at a time (in spite of the state), you can use

```
Button button = ...;
int color = ...;
ViewCompat.setBackgroundTintList(button, ColorStateList.valueOf(color));
```

This will preserve ripple effect on Lollipop and newer devices (API 21+)