# Change Button Font Style when it clicks

Tags: android, button

I want to change the button font style when it clicks how can i achieve am new in android please help

```
   Button b1=(Button)findviewbyid(R.id.login);
```

how can i select from pre_installed fonts . studio 3.0 has preinstalled fonts

Comment: Refer https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016344/2462531

Comment: how can i select pre_installed fonts . studio 3.0 have preinstalled fonts

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```
Button b1 = (Button) findViewById( R.id.login );
b1.setOnClickListener( new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Typeface newFont = getResources().getFont(R.font.myfont);
        b1.setTypeface(newFont);
    }
});
```

Comment: getfont() undefined

Comment: try this: ResourcesCompat.getFont(context, R.font.your_font);

Comment: again not defind

Answer (score 0):

Get the font you need as a .ttf  file and place it in your project's /assets/ directory.
Use this code to refer to the font and set it to your button:

```
Typeface face= Typeface.createFromAsset(getAppContext().getAssets(), "LightBlueFont.ttf"); 
button.setTypeface(face);
```

Comment: how can i select pre_installed fonts . studio 3.0 have preinstalled fonts

Comment: yo can achieve by above code. try this. change "LightBlueFont.ttf" to your font name.

Comment: android 3 has pre_instlled font