# The code that changes the style of the button in the Android Studio Kotlin file does not work

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to add a style to themes.xml so that the style changes when I click the button in the kotlin file.
My code doesn't work normally, and an error occurs.

This is my code.

themes.xml

```
<style name="borderButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.TextButton"/>
<style name="borderlessButton" parent="Widget.MaterialComponents.Button.OutlinedButton"/>
```

Fragment.kt

```
binding.btnWon.setOnClickListener {
    binding.btnFore.setBackgroundResource(R.style.borderlessButton)
    binding.btnWon.setBackgroundResource(R.style.borderButton)
}

binding.btnFore.setOnClickListener {
    binding.btnWon.setBackgroundResource(R.style.borderlessButton)
    binding.btnFore.setBackgroundResource(R.style.borderButton)
}
```

The style resource used in the kotlin code is accessible, but the "android.content.res.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f140455" occurs in that area.

How can we solve this? Please provide a solution.
Thanks!

Comment: `setBackgroundResource` expects a Drawable resource, not a Style resource.

Comment: See here https://stackoverflow.com/a/2016344/506796 You can't set the style programmatically, but you can create a state list and modify its state.

Comment: Oh, and here's a library that seems to support changing the style programmatically. https://github.com/airbnb/paris

Comment: If "Paris" is applied, it seems possible to change it be changed programmatically. I don't think it's used well in a normal environment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot set a style as a background resource directly in Kotlin or Java code. Instead, you need to set a drawable resource that uses the style as its background.

Comment: The much higher answer rate and the verboseness suggest this has been generated by [ChatGPT_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned).

Comment: I also think it is highly likely that this answer was generated by ChatGPT.